# What's the equation that produces 1 -> 105, 2 -> 120, 3 -> 135 and so on?

Tags: functions, pattern-recognition

This is the trend:

> 1 -> 105
>
> 2 -> 120
>
> 3 -> 135

As you can see the numbers on the right start at 105 and increment by 15 each time. How to take the numbers on the left to produce the numbers on the right?

Comment: $n \mapsto 90+15n$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f:\Bbb Z^+\to\Bbb Z^+$ where $f(x)=90+15x$. Note $\Bbb Z^+$ is the set of positive integers.